# Is there better way to get the difference between two table with same fields?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as below:

```
table1:

+----+----------+-------+
| id | order_id | price |
+----+----------+-------+
|  1 |     1024 |    20 |
|  2 |     1025 |    30 |
|  3 |     1026 |    35 |
|  4 |     1027 |    45 |
+----+----------+-------+

table2

+----+----------+-------+------+
| id | order_id | price | name |
+----+----------+-------+------+
|  1 |     1024 |    20 | a    |
|  2 |     1025 |    30 | b    |
|  3 |     1026 |    35 | c    |
|  4 |     1027 |    40 | d    |
+----+----------+-------+------+
```

What I want to do is just camparing fields `order_id` and `price`, and get the different content when `order_id = 1027`

Here is  my humble opinion:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT order_id, price FROM table1 

UNION ALL

SELECT order_id, price FROM table2

) t

GROUP BY order_id, price 

HAVING COUNT(*) = 1


# result 

+----------+-------+
| order_id | price |
+----------+-------+
|     1027 |    40 |
|     1027 |    45 |
+----------+-------+
```

Is there any better way to get it.

Any commentary is very welcome. great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative would be to use a `JOIN` to find non-matching prices:

```
SELECT t1.order_id, t1.price AS table1_price, t2.price AS table2_price
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.order_id = t1.order_id AND t2.price != t1.price
```

Output:

```
order_id    table1_price    table2_price
1027        45              40
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oxzVYyvTp3XBmumAhDJ2s/0)

If you also want to capture rows which exist in one table but not the other, then you will need a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, which MySQL doesn't support, and must be emulated using a `UNION` of a `LEFT JOIN` and a `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT t1.order_id AS order_id, t1.price AS table1_price, t2.price AS table2_price
      FROM table1 t1
      LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.order_id = t1.order_id
      UNION
      SELECT t2.order_id, t1.price AS table1_price, t2.price AS table2_price
      FROM table1 t1
      RIGHT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.order_id = t1.order_id) t
WHERE table1_price != table2_price OR
      table1_price IS NULL OR
      table2_price IS NULL
```

Output:

```
order_id    table1_price    table2_price
1027        45              40
1028        50              null
1029        null            45
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oxzVYyvTp3XBmumAhDJ2s/1)

Comment: what if there is only order_id `1028` in one of these two tables?

Comment: @jiaJimmy if you mean only table1 had order_id `1028`, would you want it to be displayed?

Comment: yep..It's also difference between two tables

Comment: @jiaJimmy in that case the way you are doing it is the best way as you need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` which MySQL does not support directly and has to be emulated with a `UNION` anyway. I can write up the query if you like...

Comment: Thanks for your replying,  it had a lot of benefits for me

Comment: @jiaJimmy I've added the `FULL OUTER JOIN` query so you can see how much more complicated it is than what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join to get the values

`SELECT table1.order_id, table1.price 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2  ON table2.order_id = table1.order_id AND table2.price != table1.price`